# Property 'sync' does not exist on type 'ServiceWorkerRegistration'

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Property 'sync' does not exist on type 'ServiceWorkerRegistration'
[service-worker.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzE1T.png)

[app.component.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjrRN.png)